# CREATE TABLE LIKE another table but with additional columns

Tags: postgresql, ddl

Is there a way to create a table that has the same structure as another table, but with additional columns?
From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220453/copy-table-structure-into-new-table), I can copy a table's structure with:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name ( like old_table_name including all)
```

And then I can add columns one at a time, with `ALTER TABLE new_table_name ADD COLUMN...` but I am looking for a way to do this more succinctly, like:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name ( like old_table_name including all), new_col1 new_col1_type, new_col2 new_col2_type,...
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the syntax below;

```
CREATE TABLE old_table_name (
  id serial,
  my_data text,
  primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE new_table_name ( 
  like old_table_name including all,
  new_col1 integer, 
  new_col2 text

);
```

The fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6656c/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CREATE TABLE AS <query>` option, as detailed in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html).

--Code not tested in PostgreSQL--

```
    CREATE TABLE MyNewTable
    AS
    SELECT *, CAST (NULL AS INT) AS IntCol1, CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS StrCol2...
    FROM MyOriginalTable 
     WITH NO DATA;
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no more succinct method of doing it. But `ALTER TABLE` can accept multiple arguments,

```
ALTER TABLE foo
  ADD column bar int,
  ADD column baz int;
```

Really if your goal is succinct, SQL is almost never an ideal language.