# Create table with variable name and fixed columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, table

I need to create a table daily with different names but the same set of columns. How can I do that? I find this

```
do $$ begin execute format('create table "table_%s_pk" (i int)',now()::date); end; $$;
```

which creates the table but I don't know how to include column names in this query as well.

Comment: In general, it would be a better idea to have a single table with a date column. But anyway, you already have a column name in the query; what exactly is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207097/create-table-like-another-table-but-with-additional-columns) may help. If you are thinking about [Table Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) you can look at [PG Partition Manager](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman).

Comment: Does something like this work - `create table "table_%s_pk" (i int, x varchar, y floar)',now()::date;`?

Comment: It was throwing error initially with column name but after updating postgres the problem solved! Not sure if that was the cause or something else... anyway it now works. Thanks everyone!